# Joining the Resource Table and the Resources_Role Table in a Repository using Linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I join the Resources Table to the Resources_role table where resources_id column is common in both table. Below is my code to fetch the Resources table using the Role_id, however I want all the records from the resources table that share the same resources_id column with the Resources_Role to be fetched.
How do I do this join please, below is my code

```
public IQueryable <Resources_Role> FindResourceByRoleID(int RoleId)
      {

          var roleid = from p in context.Resources_Role 
                       select p;

          roleid = roleid.Where(p => p.ROLE_ID==(RoleId));
          return roleid;
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you should watch is the method return type. Depending on what you want to return, you should adjust the return type based on result set from `JOIN` query you're using:

```
// returning resources
public IQueryable<Resources> FindResourceByRoleID(int RoleId)
{
    return (from res in context.Resources
            join role in context.Resources_Role
            on res.resources_id equals role.resources_id
            where res.ROLE_ID == RoleId
            select res);
}

// returning resource role
public IQueryable<Resources_Role> FindResourceRoleByRoleID(int RoleId)
{
    return (from role in context.Resources_Role
            join res in context.Resources
            on role.resources_id equals res.resources_id
            where res.ROLE_ID == RoleId
            select role);
}
```

Those queries above will produce SQL statements as shown below:

```
-- returns resources
SELECT t0.* FROM Resources AS t0 INNER JOIN Resources_Role AS t1
ON t0.resources_id = t1.resources_id
WHERE t0.ROLE_ID = @RoleId

-- returns resources role
SELECT t0.* FROM Resources_Role AS t0 INNER JOIN Resources AS t1
ON t0.resources_id = t1.resources_id
WHERE t1.ROLE_ID = @RoleId
```

**Note:** *Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<Resource>` to `System.Linq.IQueryable<Resources_Role>`* is self-explanatory: it occurs because your query returns `IQueryable<Resource>` but the method return type set to `IQueryable<Resources_Role>`. You must adjust the query to return `IQueryable<Resources_Role>` instead.

Comment: It works fine now after adjusting the query to return IQueryable<Resources_Role> instead. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

After you've got your roleId from your method, you could do something like the following to return a Resource:

```
var resources = from resource in context.Resources
                        where resource.ROLE_ID == roleId
                        join resource_role in context.Resources_Role 
                            on resource.resources_id equals resource_role.resource_id
                        select resource;
```

To get a Resource_Role you could do something like this:

```
var resource_role = from role in context.Resource_Roles
                            join resource in context.Resources_Role.Where(resource_role => resource_role.ROLE_ID == roleId)
                                on role.resources_id equals resource.resource_id
                            select role;
```

I'm afraid I don't have a working MVC env to test any of this in atm, but it should be a good starting point.

Comment: Ok! Thanks so much, let me try it

Comment: I just bashed this together without any testing (don't have a wokring MVC env atm), but hopefully it's at least useful

Comment: The linq query works fine, however it is throwing an exception at the point of returning resources. Below is the exceptionCannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Linq.IQueryable<----------.resource>' to
'System.Linq.IQueryable<----------.resourcerole>' An explicit conversion
exists(are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @anone I've update the answer with a solution that should return a Resource Role, let me know how it goes

Comment: @anone If you could let me know if it doesn't work, or otherwise mark this as the correct answer that would be great :)

Comment: It is throwing an exception at the point of returning resource_role, the error is below                                                                                                        
 "Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Linq.IQueryable<----------.resource>' to
'System.Linq.IQueryable<----------.resourcerole>' An explicit conversion
exists(are you missing a cast?)